# Type Error: self.text

Tags: python, scripting, objects, error, operator

After learned about new changes in blender API, I had to update script from 2.8 into 3.0 using `:` instead of `=`.

So following the changes in this script to 3.0...

```py
class ALP_OT_Params(Operator):
 
   # Old 
   #text= bpy.props.StringProperty(name= "Enter Object Name", default= "")

   # Update
   text: bpy.props.StringProperty(name= "Enter Object Name", default= "")
   
   def excute(self,context):

     new_obj_name = self.text
     obj = bpy.context.object
     obj.name = new_obj_name
```

I am getting type error at this string `obj.name = new_obj_name`.

From blender console, The error stating...

```
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: Object.name expected a bytes type, not str
```

I am not exactly sure what error was, but I am assuming it have something to do with changes in this string `text:`. I didn't have problem or getting any error on `text=` before Before Blender made API changes. What am I missing?

Couldn't find any information around that might help me to resolve my issues any suggestions?

UPDATE: Full script requested by @Gorgious & @Marty Fouts

```py
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class ALP_OT_Params(Operator):
    """Opens Add Cube with New name Dialog Box"""
    bl_idname = "alp.ot_params"
    bl_label = "Add Cube Popup Dialog"

    text: StringProperty(name="Enter Text", default="")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):

        new_obj_name = self.text

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        obj = bpy.context.object
        obj.name = new_obj_name

        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):

        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)


 def register():
     bpy.utils.register_class(ALP_OT_Params)


 def unregister():
     bpy.utils.unregister_class(ALP_OT_Params)


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     register()
     bpy.ops.alp.ot_params('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

ERROR

[image]

UPDATE: File from Blender 3.1.0

[image]

Comment: Hello, just to be sure, is `excute` a typo ? It should be `execute`

Comment: Please cut and paste the actual script as well as the _entire_ error message.  In addition to the type @Gorgious pointed out, I'm curious _where_ the error occurred.

Comment: @Gorgious, Yes it was comment typo, not on my script.

Comment: @MartyFouts, See update with full script.

Comment: and the full text of the error with the complete traceback?

Comment: @MartyFouts - I am not sure I know what is error with the complete traceback. But I posted image of error that pop up after I run this operator

Comment: I don't know what code you ran that gave you that popup but it wasn't the code that you pasted into your question.  The only problem with the code you pasted is that it has an invalid text string for `bl_idname`.  See my answer for working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the code in your example has never been run, because if it had, it would have given an error message about the `bl_idname`.  When I modify the `bl_idname`, it still won't run because there's no `scale` property.  When I disable the reference to `self.scale`, it runs fine.  Here's working code:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class ALP_OT_Params(Operator):
    """Opens Add Cube with New name Dialog Box"""
    bl_idname = "alp.params"
    bl_label = "Add Cube Popup Dialog"
    text: StringProperty(name="Enter Text", default="")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        new_obj_name = self.text
        #scale_nbr = self.scale
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        obj = bpy.context.object
        obj.name = new_obj_name
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ALP_OT_Params)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ALP_OT_Params)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.alp.params('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: After copied and pasted from your to blender editor, run and excute operator. I am still getting same error. "TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: Object.name expected a bytes type, not str"

Comment: Open a fresh copy of blender.  Go to the scripting workspace. Click "New" in the editor.  Paste the code _exactly_.  Hit the play button.  When I do that in 2.93.6, 3.0.1, or 3.1.0, the dialog pops up.  When I enter the name I get a cube with that name in the 3D Viewport.  What happens when you do it?

Comment: After following exactly to your instruction (_Copy and pasted exactly script_).  The Error occur on 3.1.0 and 3.0.1 but not on my 2.93.5

Comment: Please add a blend file showing the problem to your question because I can't reproduce your problem. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) It sounds like there's something one with your 3.x installations.

Comment: Blender file added. _See above from original post_.

Comment: and it works fine.  You have a problem with your installation.  What addons do you have enabled?

Comment: Addon was the problem!  It was my own old experimential addon that I forgot to disenage for while. After I disengage it, the script run fine. Thank you for your time truly appreciated.

Comment: @sirrus you're welcome.  I'm glad you found it and I look forward to seeing what you accomplish with add-ons.